# Troubleshooting issue with updating and displaying random quotes on interactive website using JavaScript and Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, json

I am building an interactive website using **JavaScript** and a **Node.js** app that generates random messages when the website page is refreshed. This website displays random quotes, predictions, and fun facts for each zodiac sign. However, I am having trouble updating and displaying the random quotes, predictions, and fun facts on the HTML page. I have imported the `displayQuote`, `displayPrediction`, and `displayFunFact` functions from the `display.js` module and am using a `updateResults` function to modify the text of the `li` elements for each zodiac sign. The `updateResults` function iterates over a list of zodiac signs and uses the imported functions to update the text of the `li` elements for each sign.

https://github.com/vetheve/Group-Project-Mixed-Messages.git

```
.
├── data
│   ├── funfacts.json
│   ├── predictions.json
│   └── quotes.json
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── modules
│   └── display.js
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── style.css
├── test
    └── test.js
```

- The `data` directory contains three JSON files: `funfacts.json`,
  `predictions.json`, and `quotes.json`.
- The `index.html` file is the main HTML file for the project.
- The `index.js` file contains JavaScript code for the project.
- The `modules` directory contains a single file called `display.js`, which contains additional JavaScript code for the project.
- The `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files are related to dependencies and package management in Node.js.

**HTML code `index.html`**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Astrological Insights for a Better Life</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="index.js"  type="module"></script>
        <header>
          <h1>Astrological Insights for a Better Life</h1>
        </header>
        <aside>"Welcome to the world's most accurate astrology website! ..."</aside>
        <hr>
        <h2 class="zodiac-sign">Bélier</h2>
        <ul  id="belier">
          <li>...</li>
          <li>...</li>
          <li>...</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <h2 class="zodiac-sign">Poissons</h2>
        <ul id="poissons">
          <li>...</li>
          <li>...</li>
          <li>...</li>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**JS code `index.js`**

```
    /**
     * Update the text of the li elements for each zodiac sign.
     **/
    
    // Import the displayQuote, displayPrediction, and displayFunFact functions from the display.js module
    import {
        displayQuote,
        displayPrediction,
        displayFunFact
    } from './modules/display.js';
    
    //function that updates the text of the li elements for each zodiac sign.
    function updateResults() {
        // List of zodiac signs
        const zodiacSigns = ['belier', 'taureau', 'gemeaux', 'cancer', 'lion', 'vierge', 'balance', 'scorpion', 'sagittaire', 'capricorne', 'verseau', 'poissons'];
    
        // Iterate over each zodiac sign
        for (let sign of zodiacSigns) {
            // Get the ul element for the current zodiac sign
            const ulElement = document.getElementById(sign);
    
            // Get the first li element
            const firstLi = ulElement.children[0];
    
            // Modify the text of the first li element using the displayPrediction function
            firstLi.innerText = displayPrediction();
    
            // Get the second li element
            const secondLi = ulElement.children[1];
    
            // Modify the text of the second li element using the displayQuote function
            secondLi.innerText = displayQuote();
    
            // Get the third li element
            const thirdLi = ulElement.children[2];
    
            // Modify the text of the third li element using the displayFunFact function
            thirdLi.innerText = displayFunFact();
        }
    }
```

**JS code `display.js`**

```
    // Import the 'fs' module for reading and writing files
    import fs from 'fs';
    
    // displayQuote is a function that returns a randomly selected quote from the quotes.json file along with the corresponding author.
    export const displayQuote = () => {
        // Read the quotes.json file and parse the JSON data
        const quotes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/quotes.json', 'utf8'));
    
        // Select a random index from the quotes array
        // The upper bound for the random number is the length of the quotes array minus 1 to prevent the possibility of an out-of-bounds index.
        const randomIndexQuote = Math.round(Math.random() * (quotes.length - 1));
    
        // Destructure the quote and author from the selected quote object
        const {
            quote,
            author
        } = quotes[randomIndexQuote];
    
        // Return the quote and author as a string
        return `"${quote}", ${author}`;
    };
    
    // displayPrediction is a function that returns a randomly selected prediction from the predictions.json file
    export const displayPrediction = () => {
    
        // Read the predictions.json file and parse the JSON data
        const predictions = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/predictions.json', 'utf8'));
    
        // Select a random index from the quotes array
        // The upper bound for the random number is the length of the quotes array minus 1 to prevent the possibility of an out-of-bounds index.
        const prediction = predictions.quotes[Math.round(Math.random() * (predictions.quotes.length - 1))];
    
        // Return the prediction as a string
        return `${prediction}`;
    };
    
    // displayFunFact is a function that returns a randomly selected fun fact from the funfacts.json file
    export const displayFunFact = () => {
        // Read the funfacts.json file and parse the JSON data
        const funfacts = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/funfacts.json', 'utf8'));
    
        // Select a random index from the facts array
        // The upper bound for the random number is the length of the facts array minus 1 to prevent the possibility of an out-of-bounds index.
        const funfact = funfacts.facts[Math.round(Math.random() * (funfacts.facts.length - 1))];
    
        // Return the fun fact as a string
        return `${funfact}`;
    };
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Where is your node.js server gile which serves html content? You probably need to user node.js with express wit any template engine like EJS or Jade. You can not use node/npm modules like fs with static JS. You can also use https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html to quicklt generate the server code with engine.

Comment: Hey there, I'm a newbie in the JS world trying to get my node server up and running on a local host or in VS code. It seems like I might need to go back to the basics and brush up on my skills. I didn't even know about cool frameworks like express with template engines like EJS or Jade. And I think it's probably a smart idea to avoid using node/npm modules like fs with static JS, unless I want to end up with a mountain of code that just won't work. Thank you.

Comment: You don't require node.js if it's just static quotes. Plain JS with html is enough for you.